# Token not Noticed when Pushing to Github

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, access-token, keychain, iterm2

I have a MacOS laptop and have encountered this error when pushing to GitHub, but have not being able to fix this problem, so I am looking for some help.

**remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.**

I have generated a personal access token successfully in GitHub.

In **keychain access**, when I type github it does not come up with **gitub.com**, but instead comes up with **com.microsoft.vs.liveshare: UserInfo** (for my Visual Studio Code Live Share) and **vscodevscode.github-authentication**.

I put my token password in vscodevscode.github-authentication and when I access  com.microsoft.vs.liveshare with my computer password twice, I can see that the password has expire at the beginning of it.

Now using my iTerm2 command line with zsh shell, when I go to push to GitHub, it accepts my GitHub username and then has a padlock when accepting password.

So with the padlock, it only accepts my computer login and not the personal access token I have created and I still get the same password authentication message.

Why is my personal access token not working, does it need to be configured better ?

Comment: The little padlock icon just means that what you're typing in, in iterm, isn't being saved away somewhere that someone could steal it. The zsh and iterm stuff is thus all just red herrings. I don't know what the *right* answer is, but you have to get the OSX keychain updated somehow—it has something saved that you don't want saved.

Comment: @torek  Hi Torek

I can see that you don't quite know the solution.

Just a quick question though on something that may help me understand some part of this.
Do you have a Mac ? 
Do you know much about Password Manager that you can get for iTerm2 through Window > Password Manager ?

Comment: @torek Hi Torek

Continuing on from my last message

My Password Manager does not have any accounts for this personal access token and maybe password for GitHub account online.

I think there is meant to be token for pushing work to GitHub and password for getting into Github.com.
I just wonder if it should have an account added in Password Manager, or is the Keychain meant to control this

Comment: I do have a mac, but I don't use iterm2. Meanwhile: Git itself doesn't do password management on its own but does run *credential helpers*. On OS X, Git runs `git-credential-osxkeychain`. I don't use this with Git either though, as it's specifically and only for `https` access with passwords, and I use `ssh` instead. But GitHub have this on *their* pages: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

Comment: It seems like you've already done that, though, and that's the end of what I know about in terms of using https access on OS X. ... Hm, doing some google searching, it looks like iterm2 *does* have *its own* keychain / password stuff in it, so maybe it's not a red herring after all. At least one page claims that iterm2's password manager *uses* OSX keychain, though.

Comment: Yes I do use https access with passwords.
I just wondering if this problem is to do with my git credentials setup.

When I type git config -l in my command line it shows 
credential.helper=osxkeychain
and credential.helper=cache

Before I setup my token I didn't use to have to type in a username and password to push to GitHub.
Researching the other day, I think I have cache credentials.
To me it seems that maybe I may need to switch from cache credentials to oxskeychain credentials.  The osxkeychain is built in for MacOS, but maybe it needs to be configured properly though.

Comment: Aha, the `credential.helper = cache` could be the culprit here. If you have a cached password (rather than PAT), and there's no OS X keychain entry result, Git will move on from any failure from `git-credential-osxkeychain` (assuming it returns failure, which again I don't use it, so I don't know if it does) to `git-credential-cache`, which could then return success and say "use this here password", which would then fail.

Comment: You can unset *that* setting, or use any method that will clear out a cached password from the `cache` credential helper's cache. VonC has some answers that describe how to do the latter.

Comment: Hi Torek

It is starting to make sense now, I think that the cause of the problem is the cache credential.
In google I typed git-credential-cache, the fourth result down the page says Is there a way to cache https credentials for pushing commits ?
It says To cache your GitHub password in Git when using HTTPS, you can use a credential helper to tell Git to remember your GitHub username and password

So this confirms that I have mine currently set with cache and I have to unset it.

Who is Von C , does he have a website about this ?

Comment: [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)

Comment: So once I have worked out how to unset cache , would I have to get it set to the osxkeychain so that it accepts the personal access token for git pushing as well as the password for logging into github.com online ?

Comment: Once I have the token set so that I can use it as a password to push work to github ,
I will have to find a way so that I don't have to keep typing the token every time I push to github.

Do you happen to know how set it to do this ?

Comment: I don't know. All I know here are general outlines. I think https is the wrong access method and you should use ssh instead; that's what I do. The authentication system in http/https is a mess, it was not a clean design to start and it has layer after layer of crud in it, though it does obviously work somewhat. The authentication system in ssh was well-thought-out from the start and Just Works.

Comment: Hi Torek

Because I am using https , I feel that it would be best for me to work with this.
I don't want to get myself confused by switching over to ssh at the moment and get into more trouble. Maybe down the line when I get a bit more confident with understanding difference between SSH and https then I can switch.
I can see that you probably can't provide too much help for me.
One positive thing though,  it looks like we've established it is my cache credential.
So I have to figure out how to unset that and reset it for keychain. If you know anyone using https they maybe help here.